# Purpose of @ in ERB templates

Tags: ruby, syntax, erb

I've frequently seen code like this in ERB templates:

```
<%= @some_variable %>
```

And seen code like this:

```
<%= node[:some_attribute][:some_other_attribute] %>
```

And just plain old

```
<%= some_variable %>
```

Is there a difference?  Should I be concerned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the @ is used if it is an instance variable. The most common use of these will be in a controller when you want to pass a variable up to the view that will render it.

For example you might have

```
class FooController < ApplicationController

def show
    @foo = Foo.find_by_id(params[:id]) 
end

end
```

And then in the corresponding show page you could access foo by calling:

```
<%= @foo.bar %>
```

This is useful when you will be rendering many show pages with many different foos.